# Add new Google sheet row when new value exists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, zapier

I have two Google spreadsheets, A and B: A gets replaced every day when a scheduled report copies over it and B remains the same (and is the one I want to update).

On a scheduled basis, I want to take email addresses that appear in A and see if they also exist in B. If they don't, then I want them added to a new row in B.

I have tried coming up with a way to automate this - either through macros or Zapier and I'm coming up short. All I want to know is if this is possible and what the best way to accomplish this would be. (I'm thinking of paying a contractor to do this, but I don't really know what I'd be asking for at this stage.)

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script in one of your sheet,
In your sheet open the script editor, by clicking on tool > Script editor.

create a function let's say :

```
function saveAtoB(e){
}
```

then on the left menu you have some clock icon, where you can add triggers.
click on add trigger button (right bottom).

- select your saveAtoB function,
- select HEAD
- select trigger on time
- select daily.

then save.

The automation part is Done, quite easy.

Now it is quite easy to write the code inside the saveAtoB function, if your are familiar to code in JavaScript. Else it could be little tricky.

If you share a copy of your sheet I might help.

(I suggest not to pay a contractor to do this since it probably would take less that one hour).

Comment: Thanks! Good to know this is possible. I am not familiar with JavaScript unfortunately